# maxReceivedMessageSize and Streaming in wcf

Tags: .net, wcf

I put maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800" transferMode="Streamed".  Shouldn't streaming be more benevolent toward that value?  Stream is stream and so let it pull little by little.  And yet later on there is "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (52428800) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element..."

I know that streamed implies that the server's RAM won't be overloaded, but how is it else different from buffered?

Comment: AFAIK, the transfer mode don't affect the message size.

Answer (score 5):

The `maxReceivedMessageSize` quota is a `long` value, so you can effectively set it to infinity (I'd be surprised if you can transfer more than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes, or about 8 **exabytes** - yes, I had to look up the one after peta). On streaming mode you can also set the `maxBufferSize` quota to limit how much data will be buffered in RAM at a given time.

Comment: That's useful note about RAM.  But does streaming takes place?  I've read something that it is buffered (where).  From my experiment though, when I returned FileStream from wcf, client was reading only about 1500 bytes per stream.Read(...) which implies actual streaming I guess.